# How to configure multiple databases in Hibernate with spring boot application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

In my project, there is a requirement to use different databases. We are currently using MySql database with Hibernate as ORM layer. And we are hibernate SessionFactory to query the database.

Now there is a requirement to use SQLite database as well. I have found several examples on the internet but they are all using JdbcTemplate.

https://blog.pranavek.com/using-multiple-datasource-in-spring-boot-application/

https://scattercode.co.uk/2016/01/05/multiple-databases-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-jpa/

But my requirement is to use separate sessionFactories for both the databases.
Please, help me in receiving that.

Comment: the second example has what you want

Comment: second example is relevant because it is using two configs `FooConfig` and `BarConfig` classes to initialize two datasources from two different property prefixes namely `spring.datasource` and `spring.jpa`